# Support for (this) in unobtrusive ajax callback?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

I cannot understand what kind of object the console is logging, and how to identify the HTML object.

Here is my scenario:

1.**The Form:**

*!Note:* The Id of output `<form></form>` is overriden with `new {id="ABCDEF"}`

```asp
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Add", "Home", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess="doWork(this)"}, new {id="ABCDEF"}))
{
    <div id="popup-container">
        <-- Some Data to post -->
        <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
    </div>
}
```

2.**The script**

```javascript
<script> 
  function doWork(e){
      console.log(e);    // Log 'e' parameter, passed upper, as 'this' inside OnSuccess='doWork(this)'
  }
</script>
```

3.**The console output**

```javascript
Object {
  url: "http://localhost:13350/Home/Add?Length=6", 
  isLocal: false, 
  global: true, 
  type: "POST", 
  contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; 
  charset=UTF-8"…
}
```

4.**Some Observations**:

- The `e` variable is of type [Object] object
- Inside output of `console.log(e)`, I can find all the parameters passed to `Ajax.BeginForm()` helper. *Eg:* The generated URL; Action type, even the id - if dig deeper through [Object]'s properties.

5.**Some QUESTIONs:**

1.What kind of Object is this? How can I access the generated HTML `<form></form>`?

2.How to get the `id` (whose value must be `ABCDEF`) of the logged object **STRICTLY** through the `e` parameter inside `doWork(e)` function ? Eg: `jQuery(e).attr("id")`

Thank you!

## Update 1 - the HTML beginning of the form

```
<form action="/Home/Add" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-success="doWork(this)" id="ABCDEF" method="post">
```

## Solution:

If somebody is interested in, please check Daniel's J.G. post, he gave a full answer.

## Update 2

### Since ASP.NET MVC 5.1, 'this' is available by default inside unobtrusive ajax library, see [changelog](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/mvc51-release-notes#thisContext) from Microsoft

Comment: 1. You should read the syntax of the `OnSuccess()` method. Once the `onSuccess()` method is being invoked, you will be in a new context and I guess that `this` has a different value. You can even try to do `console.log( arguments );` to see if it gives you more parameters. Also, you can do `var that = this;` and give `that` param along with `doWork(that)`

Comment: 2. I'm not familiar with the ASP part, but you can maybe pass this ID parameter along with the `onSuccess` and it might return you in the onSuccess method.

Comment: #EricG Thank you for your answer. It's a good point, but I need something generic. So I have pointed out in the question that I need STRICTLY through the `e` param. ASP.NET MVC generates unique ID's for every `Ajax.BeginForm()`. So if I had more than 1 form, they still would be unique. In other case if I override the `id` it means that I should take care of `<form></form>`-id uniqueness. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use @Ajax.BeginForm you are just adding data-ajax attributes to the form html element, so the javascript code in jquery.unobtrusive-ajax can actually call the jquery [ajax function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

This is done by setting a live (now deprecated and replaced by `on`, but the jquery.unobtrusive code in MVC 3 uses an old version of jquery) event handler on forms with data-ajax=true submit event:

```
$("form[data-ajax=true]").live("submit", function (evt) {
    var clickInfo = $(this).data(data_click) || [];
    evt.preventDefault();
    if (!validate(this)) {
        return;
    }
    asyncRequest(this, {
        url: this.action,
        type: this.method || "GET",
        data: clickInfo.concat($(this).serializeArray())
    });
});

//Where asyncRequest will build the options object for the ajax function 
//and will call the ajax function
```

The parameters for the jquery ajax method are retrieved from the data-ajax attributes in the html form element, which were generated in the server side from the arguments to the @Ajax.BeginForm helper.

The OnSuccess parameter is just setting the data-ajax-success attribute which will in turn be used for the `success` option passed to the jquery [ajax function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

If you check the jquery documentation, there is a `context` option in the ajax function that can be used to set the context (i.e. the `this` object) in the callback functions (the success/error/complete callbacks). **When no context is passed, the context will be set as an object will all the options for the jquery ajax call**:

> context Type: PlainObject
>
> This object will be made the context of all
>   Ajax-related callbacks. By default, the context is an object that
>   represents the ajax settings used in the call ($.ajaxSettings merged
>   with the settings passed to $.ajax). For example, specifying a DOM
>   element as the context will make that the context for the complete
>   callback of a request, like so

Because the jquery.unobtrusive-ajax code is not passing a context option to the ajax call, what you see in the debugger is the object with all the options passed to the jquery ajax function.

Of course one option is to pass a parameter to your function like `OnSuccess="doWork(this, 'yourFormId')"` but I understand you might want a more generic approach.In that case, you could modify the source of the jquery-unobtrusive-ajax code to either:

- Set the context to the form element that is being posted. This way
  `this` in your success function will be the form html element

  ```
  $("form[data-ajax=true]").live("submit", function (evt) {
      var clickInfo = $(this).data(data_click) || [];
      evt.preventDefault();
      if (!validate(this)) {
          return;
      }
      asyncRequest(this, {
          url: this.action,
          type: this.method || "GET",
          context: this //SET CONTEXT TO THE FORM HTML ELEMENT
          data: clickInfo.concat($(this).serializeArray())
      });
  });
  ```
- Add another option with the form to the options object. This way you
  can do `this.form` in your success function to get the form html
  element.

  ```
  $("form[data-ajax=true]").live("submit", function (evt) {
      var clickInfo = $(this).data(data_click) || [];
      evt.preventDefault();
      if (!validate(this)) {
          return;
      }
      asyncRequest(this, {
          url: this.action,
          type: this.method || "GET",
          form: this //ADD A FORM PARAMETER TO THE CONTEXT OBJECT
          data: clickInfo.concat($(this).serializeArray())
      });
  });
  ```

I have created [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asYdU/3/) (setting your `doWork` function as the success/error callbacks) so you can try both options.

Hopefully I have explained myself and all of this makes sense!

Comment: Daniel J.G. Thank you very much for your time. I appreciate your efforts. Your solution is perfect! (handshake)

Comment: Glad to be of help! (It was an interesting question :))